# Fusion Chart Tooltip

Tags: javascript, ios, ios4, uiwebview, flash

I have implemented the Fusion chart(SWF & JS) in my iPad application web view. I want to implement tooltip & drilldown for graph. Single tap should show the tooltip & double tap should drill drown the graph. How can I do this...

Comment: What have you done? Could you post some code too?

Comment: I need debug information; what is the output of FusionCharts.debugMode.enabled( function() { console.log(arguments); } , 'verbose');